# AWS network-acl blocking nginx dns resolution

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, network-security

I'm trying to lock down ports on my subnets, and am having a problem with an nginx instance that I'm running on ECS.

Traffic comes into the system on `:443` to an ELB, which routes some of it to an nginx instance running on ECS, which `proxy_pass`-es it on to an external www address.

The nginx is set to `proxy_pass` to a domain name, and it's using an nginx resolver configuration: `resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off valid=10s` to resolve that to an IP address. The IP is not static, so I have to do this.

However, when I apply my network acl, everything works except for this dns resolution. The nginx returns Bad Gateway responses complaining that my domain `could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)`.

The network acl is setup to allow all outbound traffic for all protocols, but limits inbound traffic to a specific set of ports.

I've tried adding 53 (UDP and TCP) into the inbound rules, but resolution still fails.

It's important to note that if I allow all inbound traffic then the dns resolution works.

My question is either:

1. What do I need to do to get the nginx resolver working when my network acl is applied?
2. I know that every VPC comes with a DNS server so as to route AWS DNS names to VMs. Could I use that as my resolver instead?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to allow all traffic coming in from 8.8.8.8.

However, it's important to note that some AWS services (like ELBs) use Ephemeral Ports (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports), and these must be open as well.

Granted, they represent a large port range, but as that documentation states, you can always DENY traffic from malicious ports.